# Calling JAX webservices from php is not working

Tags: java, php, web-services

I am trying to call Java webservices developed using JAX-WS 2.1.4 from php but it doesnt seem to work as expected. All the parameter values being passed to the method has been intrepreted as "null" value, but i am passing the proper values from php side.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: I'd love to help... if you perhaps posted the code you were using...

Comment: Here is the code:

$soapObj = new SoapClient('some.wsdl');
$response = $soapObj->method('test', 'test', 1);

Answer (score 0):

try

$soapObj->method(array('arg0' => 'test', 'arg1' => 'test, 'arg2' => 1));